# How can I remove a specific character from a string in Perl?

Tags: regex, perl, string, replace

I'm trying to remove a specific character from a string in Perl:

```
my $string="MATTHATBAT";
substr($string, 2, 1, '');
```

EDIT: This does work, sorry. Leaving this here in case someone needs to know how to do this.

Also, is there  a more efficient way of doing this?

The string should now be MATHATBAT.

Am I missing something? I know that I can use regex s///, but I am iterating through the string, looking for a certain character (this char changes), then removing the character (but only that character at that offset). So eventually, I will be removing the second or third occurence of the character (i.e. MATTHABAT, MATTHATBA and even MATHABAT etc)

Can I maybe do this using search and replace? I am using a for loop to iterate through offsets.

Comment: Ah, yes, I see it works now in a new script. I'll figure the problem out, but is there a better way of doing this? It doesn't seem super efficient this way.

Comment: The problem still isn't clear - what determines the character to remove? that it's a duplicate? and do you want to remove the subsequent instances of that character, but not any instances preceding the first character removed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a benchmark comparing regexp vs substr:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
use 5.10.1;
use warnings;
use strict;
use Benchmark qw(:all);

my $count = -3;
my $r = cmpthese($count,
  {
    'substring' => sub {
        my $string = "MATTHATBAT";
        substr($string, 2, 1, ''); 
    },
    'regexp' => sub {
        my $string = "MATTHATBAT";
        $string =~ s/(.{2})./$1/;
    },
  }
);
```

Result:

```
               Rate    regexp substring
regexp     162340/s        --      -93%
substring 2206122/s     1259%        --
```

As you can see, substr is about 13.5 times as fast as regex.

@Sinan Ünür 1259% is 13.5 times and not 12.5 times.

Comment: That's eye-opening. I guess it being easier to write doesn't make it easier to run or faster :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your example does work. The `$string` will contain `MATHATBAT` as you wanted to have, the problem is somewhere else, not in this part.

Comment: Thanks, I see it now. I'll dig for the error :) Is there a better way of doing this, do you know? Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You can loop the reg.exp matches with //g

from [perlrequick](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick.html) :

```
   $x = "cat dog house"; # 3 words
   while ($x =~ /(\w+)/g) {
       print "Word is $1, ends at position ", pos $x, "\n";
   }
```

*think* you can modify $x while iterating .. or you could store pos $x in an array and remove then afterwards